# PHP echo variable validation

Tags: php, variables, echo

Trying to do a simple validation.
Tutorial shows this in order to do a validation:

```
<input type="text" name="userName" required tabindex=1><?php if (!is_null($user)) {echo 'value = "'. $user->getUserName() .'"';}?>
```

However on my file the "value=" displays on my page.
So I tried this, putting value inside or outside PHP tags still yields no results.

```
First name:     
<input type="text" name="firstName" <?php echo 'value = "'. $userData->getFirstName() .'"';?> required tabindex=1>
```

Comment: If the tutorial omits the need to preventing XSS, you should move on some other tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently you echo the value outside the close of input, so the browser displays it:

```
<input type="text" name="userName" required tabindex=1><?php if (!is_null($user)) {echo 'value = "'. $user->getUserName() .'"';}?>
```

change to

```
<input type="text" name="userName" required tabindex=1 
<?php if (!is_null($user)) {echo 'value = "'. $user->getUserName() .'"';}?>
 >
```

demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/0Zf5EW

Comment: Well... I can't compete with that; not with a demo too.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it comes with free postage and a redeem by mail coupon for cheese - too!

Comment: *Augh!*, you just reminded me; I totally forgot about the `$_POST` office. *grazie*